# jQuery: Select particular element from given id and set focus on it. Optimized way

Tags: javascript, jquery

At many places i have to set focus on field that is visible and i can have multiple field visible based on different scenario. For example:

```
<input id="A">
<input id="B">
```

Situation is any of these two input can be visible and i have to set focus on that.

What i am doing right now:

```
if ($('#A').is(":visible")) {
    $('#A').focus();
} else if ($('#B').is(":visible")) {
    $('#B').focus();
}
```

I feel there could be better optimized way of doing this. I want to remove this if else if statement.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `:visible` selector and `first()` as follow

```
$('#A:visible, #B:visible').first().focus();
```

`$('#A:visible, #B:visible')` will select the elements with id `A` and `B` and is currently visible, so basically selecting/filtering only visible elements from with the given ids.

`first` will get the first element from the matched set

`focus` will set the element to focus.

Answer (score 0):

You can chain the functionality like so:

```
$('#A, #B').filter(':visible').focus()
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
$('#A, #B').filter(':visible').first().focus();
```